# Почему smtplib теряет пробел в длинных заголовках письма?

Tags: python, email, smtplib

Пытаюсь отправить письмо с кириллическими символами через `smtplib`:

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
from smtplib import SMTP_SSL


def send_email():
    msg = EmailMessage()

    msg.set_content('some text')
    msg.set_type('text/plain;')
    msg.set_charset('utf-8')

    msg['Subject'] = 'Отзывы Удобство работы с сайтом <= 5'
    msg['From'] = 'Автоматизированная система контроля качества <from@domain.ru>'
    msg['To'] = ['to@domain.ru']

    server = SMTP_SSL('host', 465)
    server.login('login', 'password')
    server.send_message(msg)
    server.quit()
```

Письма отправляются и доходят, но я заметил, что иногда у заголовков `From` или `Subject` пропадает пробел между некоторыми словами.

Вот пример проблемного заголовка:
`Отзывы Удобство работы с сайтом <= 5`

Я знаю, что при дефолтных настройках `smtplib` бьет длинные заголовки (более 78 символов) на части и кодирует их в base64. Закодированный заголовок выглядит примерно так:

`=?utf-8?b?0J7RgtC30YvQstGLINCj0LTQvtCx0YHRgtCy0L4g0YDQsNCx0L7RgtGL?= =?utf-8?b?0YEg0YHQsNC50YLQvtC8?= <= 5`

Проблема в том, что когда вторая строка начинается с пробела, `smtplib` его просто игнорирует и в закодированной части его уже нет. В моем заголовке строки бьются вот так:

- Первая строка: `Отзывы Удобство работы`
- Вторая строка:  `с сайтом <= 5` (первый символ - пробел)

То есть, после кодирования-раскодирования заголовка он выглядит вот так:

`Отзывы Удобство работыс сайтом <= 5`

Это баг smtplib или я что-то делаю не так? Можно ли как-то "научить" `smtplib` видеть пробел в начале строки и тоже кодировать его в base64?

**P.S.** Я знаю, что можно увеличить максимальную длину одной строки, тогда заголовок не будет разбиваться на части и пробел не пропадает:

`msg = EmailMessage(policy=default.clone(max_line_length=500))`.

Но RFC 2047 рекомендует длину строки 78 символов. Можно ли забить на эту рекомендацию и чем это черевато?